# Facebook like button disappeared in some pages

Tags: facebook-like

I have a problem to install facebook like button to my PmWiki site.

Some of pages work with the button fine but some not. I have tried to study the script got from facebook and found the span and iframe are all with 0 width and 0 height.

So I tried input the URL with problem to the like button plugin page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

While I filled URL with problem like: http://www.newland-id.com/techwiki/index.php?n=Products.Products in the URL box of plugin page. I saw nothing on the right.

But same site some other pages work fine like above URL replace ?n=Products.Products to ?n=NQuire.NQuire.

I have also tried to report it to facebook bug, but that is funny I can not see create bugs button in the bugs page.

Please suggest or any body help me to report this bug to facebook?